# Adding several rows into mysql table from php

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am still a beginner and I want to know if you can add several rows into a mysql table with only one command. I cannot seem to find the answer on this website.

What I have tried:

```
INSERT INTO table
  (example_id, name, value1, value 2)
VALUES
  (100, 'Name 1', 'Value 1', 'Value 2'),
```

and kept on copying and pasting this and changing the name and values.

Comment: Is this a mysql question or a php question? In sql you can insert multiple rows with one insert statement or load data from a file with loaddata.

Comment: You can control a mysql table and database using php, so it is both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` (`user_id`, `user_name`) VALUES
(1, 'aaa'),
(2, 'bbb'),
(3, 'ccc');
```